# Pre-highlight a set of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which has a set of `divs` that are highlight-able by clicking and dragging the mouse over these boxes. Each boxes represent a value with an increment of five. E.g 1st box is 0.5, 2nd is 1, and so on. When you highlight the divs it will return an array that contains the highlighted value.

If I have preset values. E.g `var x = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 5, 5.5];`. How will I be able to highlight the `divs` matching the values in `array x`

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/guugmyn2/

`var x = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 5, 5.5];` [Image of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh5Dk.png)

Here's the code:

```
function calculateArray() {
  var x = [];
  $("div.range-bar").each(function(index, value) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("highlight"))
      x.push(0.5 + index / 2);
  });
  return x;
}
var x = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $range = $('.range-bar').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    var flag = $(this).hasClass('highlight');
    $range.on('mouseenter.highlight', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('highlight', flag);
    });


  });
  $(document).mouseup(function() {
    $('.range-bar').off('mouseenter');
    x = calculateArray();
  });
});
```

Comment: Post relevant code in the question itself. Questions need to be self contained. We shouldn't have to go off site just to review your issues. Use demos only to support what is actually in the question

Comment: @charlietfl I just wanted to include the fiddle so that they can visualize what I'm talking about easily but I included the code as you said :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function calculateArray() {
  var x = [];
  $("div.range-bar").each(function(index, value) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("highlight"))
      x.push(0.5 + index / 2);
  });
  return x;
}
var x = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 5, 5.5];

$(document).ready(function() {
var arr = x.toString().split(',');

$.each(arr,function(i){

   var double="";
   var double=parseFloat(arr[i])+parseFloat(arr[i]);

   $("div.range-bar:nth-child("+double+")").toggleClass('highlight');
});
  var $range = $('.range-bar').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    var flag = $(this).hasClass('highlight');
    $range.on('mouseenter.highlight', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('highlight', flag);
    });


  });
  $(document).mouseup(function() {
    $('.range-bar').off('mouseenter');
    x = calculateArray();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This is pretty close to what I'm hoping for but I want to be able to re-highlight those highlighted values again.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're awesome!